# UIView drawInRect with UIImage results in blackbackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimage

I have this following codes:

```
@implementation MyImageView
@synthesize image; //image is a UIImage
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

}
return self;
}
-(void) removeFromSuperview
{
self.image = nil;
[super removeFromSuperview];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
if (self.image)
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    //the below 2 lines is to prove that the alpha channel of my UIImage is indeed drawn
    //CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    //CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, self.image.CGImage);


}
}
@end
```

When I ran the code, I realized that the background of my view is black. To test if it was a problem with my UIImage, I used the 2 lines commented after CGContextClearRect(context, rect). Indeed a white background was drawn. Is there anyway for me to remove the black background? When I init MyImageView, i have already set backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor].

Any advice is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: why dont you just uncomment the 2 lines?

Comment: when I uncomment the 2 lines, my background will be white. I need the image's alpha to blend with the background

Comment: oh ok yes you are right now i got it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the background color to `[UIColor clearColor]` should work. Also set `self.opaque = NO` to enable transparency.

You should also check that the correct initializer is being called. For example if the view is part of a XIB file, you need to implement `initWithCoder:` as well as `initWithFrame:` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I have already set it. Turns out that I did not do it for my test case. A false alarm, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Where do you set the background. I am using my image in an attributed string not a UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - this worked for me (Swift example)

```
    var backgroundImage = UIImage() //background image - size = 100x100
    var frontImage = UIImage()  //smaller image to be drawn in the middle

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 100), false, 0.0) //false here indicates transparent

    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)

    backgroundImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    frontImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake((100 - frontImage.size.width) / 2, (diameter - frontImage.size.height) / 2, frontImage.size.width, frontImage.size.height))

    UIGraphicsPopContext()

    var outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CGContext will draw upside down
anyhow, so just go the easy route and use

```
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(rect)];
```

Instead.

Comment: That was my original code. It did not work as well. Strange enough, my current code did not draw upside down...